# How to Fetch specific numbers of emails either using imap or pop3 in java?

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have to fetch fix number emails using imap or pop3 protocol and java mail service . is there any way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is your code?  This question is not particularly constructive as is.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case, fetch command can be used:

FETCH 2:4 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (To)])

This command will fetch messages with UID 2 to 4 and fetch required information.

In case of JavaMail API I guess this kind of method is not expose, so firstly do a fast fetch to get meta data, and then iterate over the required number of messages fetching each one at a time.

There's a way to do fast fetch using fetchprofile.

I don't remember exactly as I tried it long time back. But this should be a head start.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the Folder.getMessages method to get Message objects for the set of messages you want to fetch.  The getMessages method does **not** fetch any message data.

Next, depending on what you're doing, you might want to use the Folder.fetch method to prefetch some message metadata (e.g., headers).  This is more useful with IMAP than with POP3.  Note that the fetch method can be applied to the array of Message objects you got in the first step.

Finally, iterate over the Message objects you got in the first step and access the data you need for each message.  This is when the message data will actually be fetched from the server.